# WPF Passing DataGrid Data on double click

Tags: c#, wpf

Currently I have a datagrid that is populated with database info.
When you double click a row I have been able to successfully handle programically but now I am trying to tackle passing data.
Is there anyway to accomplish this using my current setup or do I need to re-write the way I am handling the double click.

Here is the XAML.

```
<DataGrid Name="DgMain" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="auto" Margin="10,43" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="DgMain_SelectionChanged"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
              IsReadOnly="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="DgMain_DoubleClick"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
```

Here is the code behind.

```
private void DgMain_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(sender.ToString());
    }
```

This code works, I get the Messagebox showing that the sender is the DataGrid, I am stuck on how to check the item that was click though. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: IMHO, you should be using utilizing MVVM. Anyways, create a class that would hold your data, then construct this class with your columns/rows data and pass this off... I also see `SelectedItem` is this a property or? `SelectedItem` is what you want to go after once you double click the row...

Comment: I am kind of stumbling into WPF from a windows form world so I really have no idea what I am doing, I will need to determine how to use MVVM with WPF. Appreciate pointing me in that direction.

Comment: Would the clicked item be the SelectedItem that you have bound in the XAML?

Comment: Yes that is correct @RobGoodwin

Comment: Thank you @Çöđěxěŕ that post helped me immensely, I was able to do exactly as you said and use the table class I had already created and pulled from DgMan.SelectedItem to dump the data into a new instance of that class.

Comment: @G_Man you are welcome, glad that helped you solve your issue.